# Test in cloud button has gone

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-test-cloud

I made a 'Xamarin UI Test' Project to test my app.
I was able to click in the button like this: [Run in Test Cloud button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjsTk.png).

But now i made my test using the Repl() and  want to run it in the cloud the button has gone away.

What i have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause of the Issue

It looks like you are hitting this bug: [Bug 52372 - "Run in Test Cloud" option no longer appears in menu on C9](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52372)

That issue is reported on this version for Xamarin 4.3.0.636. Note that it may happen in other versions but this is the initial version the bug was reported against. You can track the status of that issue either directly in the report on [Xamarin's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52372), and/or you can watch for a release announcement on the [Xamarin Releases Blog](http://releases.xamarin.com/).

## Workarounds

#### Downgrading Xamarin

While waiting for a fix to become available, you can downgrade to the previous `Cycle 8` version of Xamarin by going to “Get the latest stable version of Cycle 8” section on your account page: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads#cycle8.

#### Uploading to Test Cloud via the Command Line

Alternatively, you can upload tests to the Test Cloud through the command line. To do this log into https://testcloud.xamarin.com & click "New Test Run" at the top. (Note this option is only visible if you have a currently valid Test Cloud account or trial.)

This launches a wizard which will have you pick some options (like whether you want to use Android or iOS; etc.), and at the end will generate a *prototype* command line. Below is an example for Android:

> packages\Xamarin.UITest.[version]\tools\test-cloud.exe submit yourAppFile.apk [API_KEY] --devices [DEVICE_HASH] --series "master" --locale "en_US" --user [EMAIL] --assembly-dir pathToTestDllFolder

**Note:** I have removed the [API_KEY], [DEVICE_HASH] & [EMAIL] values for privacy reasons, however these will automatically be included when you generate the prototype from the wizard in Test Cloud.

You will still have to manually update the `Xamarin.UITest.[version]` as well as the *actual* names and relative paths of `yourAppFile.apk` & `pathToTestDllFolder` for this approach to work.